# emit function in socket.io not receiving at other end with large data

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have emit function on client which is sending data array of over 3000 objects. However it never gets recieved on the other end (server).Surprisingly, When I reduced the size of array it receives on the server.I am using nginx on server. Is there a maximum message size setting in nginx.confg file that can be altered to increase the amount of data received on server.

Comment: Try converting to `JSON string` on client `JSON.stringify()` then convert back on server to js Object `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @wrangler - socket.io already does the `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` automatically for you.  There is no need to manually do it.

Comment: Related, but perhaps a bit old so I won't mark as a dup: [Nginx as a proxy for webSocket for big messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543787/nginx-as-a-proxy-for-nodejssocket-io-everything-is-ok-except-for-big-messages).  Also perhaps relevant: [Nginx reverse proxy for socket.io dropping messages at a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874781/nginx-reverse-proxy-for-socket-io-dropping-messages-at-a-certain-size).